# Overwriting Multiple String Variables with Loop or Apply

Tags: r, string, dataframe, loops, dplyr

I am trying to use a loop or apply to more than one variable in a data frame to remove some accents without creating new variables. Here is an example data frame with two grandfathers, their sons' names, and how many grandchildren they have:

```
df <- data.frame(
        grandfather = c("Ramón", "Chris"), 
        son = c("José", "Mike"),
        grandchildren = c(3,4))
```

Now I create a function to remove the accents in José and Ramón:

```
remove.accents <- function(s) {
  old1 <- "óé"
  new1 <- "oe"
  s1 <- chartr(old1, new1, s)
}
```

Clearly, I could do this by just overwriting each variable one at a time:

```
df$grandfather = remove.accents(df$grandfather)
df$son = remove.accents(df$son)
```

How could I do this with a loop or apply function while still keeping the same data frame--instead of writing things one at a time? Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`across`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(across(where(is.character),remove.accents))

  grandfather  son grandchildren
1       Ramon Jose             3
2       Chris Mike             4
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, @Waldi. For some reason, it is not working for me. I just tried on two different computers, too. Any ideas? I also tried adding `where` (per the warning) and assigning it to a second data frame as well: `df2 <- df %>% dplyr::mutate(across(where(is.character),remove.accents))`. In any case, I appreciate your time and response.

Comment: @Mike, sorry I didn't mention this : you should update dplyr to 1.0.0

Comment: so first `install.packages("dplyr")` and then above code

Comment: Thank you, @Waldi! I updated to R 4.0.2. (with Rtools 4.0.0.) as well as installed the new version of dplyr, and that solved the problem. I am marking this as done -- it is a terrific solution to a seemingly simple but complex problem for `R`. Other should, however, note that even though @Waldi's solution works, `R` is now requesting the inclusion of `where` per my comments above.

Comment: Thanks @Mike for your feedback : I added the `where` to avoid the warning